# PHP / Apache2 page taking too long to load

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have some PHP code that executes some server intensive code with a lot of calculations and loops.  It typically takes 2 to 10 seconds for it to run.  But as the code is written, it should always finish (no infinite loops) and it should never take more than 10 seconds.  However, I randomly get these situations where it takes around 60 seconds for the page to load in my browser, yet the PHP microtime function is telling me it only took 2 seconds.

```
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
// All my vairous loops and calculations
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);
$g = number_format(($end_time - $start_time), 4);
echo "<br>Total Time " . $g;
```

I run my own Ubuntu 12 instance so I have complete control over server processes.  I'm not a very experienced server admin though.  My PHP.ini max_execution_time is set to 30.  Yet when I have this problem, it takes well over 30 seconds to finally appear in my browser (and then tells me it ran in 2 seconds).  What I'm wondering is if could this simply be a network issue.  If so, how do I know if it is my ISP or on the data center side? Could it also be something at the Apache service level?  Like some buffer filling up and delaying the sending of the page.

Comment: 1 - is the server on your local network? 
2- did you check on the browser as it might be a browser issue

Comment: Sorry. I should mention that the server is at a data center over the internet.  (Digital Ocean)  It happens intermittently.  It isn't a browser rendering issue such as malformed css or something.

Comment: I think it is not an Apache issue since it is informing you that the execution time is 2 seconds... It is one of two either network issue or browser issue, in fact I tend to have a doubt in the brwoser

Comment: Is this returning an array that is then being rendered in the browser as a table or list with the help of some js? If PHP's microtime is telling you it took 2 seconds, which is a very long time by the way, then it took 2 seconds and PHP is not the issue. I very much doubt that the issue is a problem with Digital Ocean as that would be front page hacker news.

Comment: Do you have have Firefox with Firebug installed or Chrome so you can see the data coming into your browser? Does the script render html? JSON? XML?

Comment: It is rendering simple HTML in a list of usually 300 lines long of data.  There is no js or any client side code other than the HTML.  So at the moment I am thinking it is an intermittent network issue.  I just wish I could think of a way to test that to be sure.